# Google Play store app on 4.2.2 AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, android-virtual-device

Is it possible to install the Google Play store app on an Android 4.2.2 AVD?

Searching stackoverflow I've come across a lot of questions asking this, but many of the answers are incomplete or are for older versions of Android.

I followed the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) and my AVD does have Google Play Services installed. However, it lacks the Google Play app. Is there a way to install it on an AVD? If not, why has Google imposed this limitation?

I'd like to be able to simulate updating system apps on a virtual device. If there's a way to accomplish this without using Google Play, that would solve my problem as well.